# Solutions tending to infinity in finite time both forwards and backwards

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Is my solution correct for the part underlined in green?**

[image]

$$x(t)=\frac{\tan(t)+x_0}{1-x_0\tan (t)}$$ so solutions go to infinity at:

$$\tan(t)=\frac{1}{x_0}$$
[image]

Where $t_2<0<t_1$

Comment: This is the correct idea. Try to express it a little more clearly. In particular, write a complete sentence that answers the question. Note that $x(t) \to \infty$ as $t$ approaches a finite value and that $x(t) \to - \infty$ as $t$ approaches another finite value. That is more information than the problem asks for, but it never hurts to spell out these extra details.

Comment: There is a unique solution within the connected period of the tangent function that contains $0$, but in each of the other connected intervals on which the function is finite, one can add a different constant of integration, getting non-unique solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} =\dot{x} = 1+x^2
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{1+x^2} = dt
$$
$$
\arctan x = t+C
$$
$$
x = \tan(t+C) = \frac{\tan t + \tan C}{1-\tan t\tan C}. \tag 1
$$
When $t=0$, this is $\tan C$, so $C=\arctan x_0$.  (We could take $C$ to be $\arctan(x_0)+n\pi$ for any integer $n$, but $(1)$ would still be the same.  If some non-rigorousness is thought to afflict the steps culminating in $(1)$, one can check the solution by substitution.

This function has vertical asymptotes at
$$
\begin{cases}
\arctan\dfrac{1}{x_0} = \dfrac\pi2 - \arctan x_0\text{ and } \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right) - \pi = \arctan(x_0)-\dfrac\pi 2  & \text{if }x_0>0, \\[8pt]
\arctan\dfrac{1}{x_0 }=-\dfrac\pi2-\arctan x_0\text{ and } \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x_0}\right) + \pi = -\arctan(x_0)+ \dfrac\pi 2 & \text{if }x_0<0, \\[8pt]
\pm\dfrac\pi2 & \text{if } x_0=0.
\end{cases}
$$
The solution is unique on the interval between these two asymptotes. It is not unique on adjacent intervals, but that is probably not of interest for contemplated applications.

How would one prove uniqueness.  Instantly I think of the mean value theorem, but then of the non-linearity of the equation.   However, the steps leading to $(1)$ can be reworked into a rigorous proof of uniqueness by citing the chain rule in the right places.

Comment: Sorry is this an alternative method or is my initial solution incorrect?

Comment: Neither --- it spells out details, but it's not clear that it's essentially different from what you did.